# UpdateProgress linked to Multiple UpdatePanel controls

Tags: asp.net-ajax, webforms

Is there a way to have a single UpdateProgress control associated with mupltiple UpdatePanel controls?  something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     .....
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     .....
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress3" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel2">.....
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think so. Trying this programmatically, it insists on having a string ID for the UpdatePanel, and gives no indication that you can associate a collection of UpdatePanels with a particular UpdateProgress control.

```
UpdateProgress1.AssociatedUpdatePanelID = "UpdatePanel1";
```

From the Metadata:

```
Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the ID of the System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel control that the System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress
        //     control displays status for.
```

So, I can't see that you can do this. Good question though.

Comment: `You can put multiple UpdateProgress controls on a page, each associated with a different UpdatePanel control. Alternatively, you can use one UpdateProgress control and associate it with all UpdatePanel controls on the page.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: If you leave the ID for associated panel blank, it would work will all updatepanel requests on page.

Answer (score 33):

Remove the AssociatedUpdatePanelID from the tag and it will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Scott,

Yes that is also an option - that means that I should probably have a single update progress control on the page that is used by all Update Panel controls, otherwise your page will light up like a Christmas tree if none of them are associated to a specific update panel - +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will directly work from properties pane of Update Progress, you can set target panel.

But, generally in most system, one progress can be targeted to single update panel control.